# Train some embeddings, keep others fixed

Tags: nlp, neural-network, deep-learning, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I do sequence classification with Keras, using an RNN and embeddings. My sequences are a bit weird. I have words mixed with special symbols. Words are associated with fixed, pre-trained embeddings, but the special symbol embeddings have to be modified during training.

In an Embedding layer during learning, how can I keep some embeddings fixed while updating others? Is there a way to mask those indices which shouldn't be modified? Or is this a case for a custom Embedding layer?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is this a problem? Are you worried about computation time?

Comment: I don't have much training data. Backpropagating into pre-trained word embeddings with less training data can be a very bad idea. However, my special symbols don't have pre-trained embeddings, so I want to backpropagate into special symbol embeddings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe that this is achievable with the existing `Embedding` layer. To get around it I would just create a custom layer that builds two embedding layers internally, and only puts the embedding matrix of one of them into the `trainable_parameters`.

Comment: Thank you for the hints. After some fiddling I got it to work.